# Foreach jQuery object in laravel blade

Tags: jquery, foreach, jqgrid, laravel-blade, increment

I'm incrementing a count for an item in a jQgrid. I'm showing a popup window where it prints a list with al the items and how many of these items. How do I foreach these items in a table?

jQuery:

```
let scannedCount = {};

function checkedFormatter(cellValue, row) {
    scannedCount[row.rowId] = 0;
    return '<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between checkCell" style="font-size: 1.8rem;">' +
        '<i class="fas fa-minus minCheck" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="decrementCount(' + row.rowId + ')"></i> ' +
        '<input class="scannedCount-' + row.rowId + '" type="text" value="' + scannedCount[row.rowId] + '" style="width: 70px;">' +
        '<i class="fas fa-plus plusCheck" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="incrementCount(' + row.rowId + ')"></i></div>'
}

function incrementCount(rowId) {
    scannedCount[rowId]++;
    $("#scannedCount-" + rowId).val(scannedCount[rowId]);
    console.log(scannedCount);
}

function shoppingCart(id) {
    openAddModal({
        type: 'shopping-cart',
        title: Lang.get('strings.shopping-cart'),
        url: '/' + id + '/shopping-cart/',
    });
}
```

shoppingcart:

```
<div class="packing-slip">
    <table class="packing-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-head" style="text-align: left;">{{__('description')}}</th>
            <th class="table-head">{{__('amount')}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    {{$shoppingCart}} = scannedCount;
</script>
```

Do I append each row or something? I can't get it to work. Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answere here [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

```
function shoppingCartItems() {
    $.each(scannedCount, function (key, value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            $('.packing-table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
        }
    })
}
```